# spark input_line like input_file_name when reading line separated json

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a new line separated json file. Each line consists of a json array which contains different type of documents. The standard behavior of spark is that when I read it naivly

```py
df = spark.read.json(file.path)
```

spark creates a new line for each document in each array, while the different document types become each a column and for each line only one is not null.

I need to recover the line number of each document as the documents on the same line have a relation which is otherwise not recoverable.

I imagined there would be something similar to `input_file_name()` but there is none. Is there a way to achieve this?

An example input is

```
[{"firstAttribute":1, "secondAttribute":2},{"firstAttribute":10, "secondAttribute":20}]
[{"firstAttribute":3, "secondAttribute":4},{"thirdAttribute":5, "secondAttribute":6}]
```

The resulting dataframe now looks like this:

| firstAttribute | secondAttribute | thirdAttribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |
| 10 | 20 |  |
| 3 | 4 |  |
|  | 6 | 5 |

Now I would like to see the linenumber of the source file for the specific entry like this

| line number | firstAttribute | secondAttribute | thirdAttribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 10 | 20 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |  |
| 2 |  | 6 | 5 |

Comment: can you post a sample of the data and anc exmple of the desired output ?

Comment: I am creating an example as I cannot share my data. Hang on